# Is transferring files over private network between two servers from remote third server possible?

Tags: ssh, scp

I've got a local machine, **Server A**. This server has a public internet connection to **Server B** and **Server C** using private **Key A**. Neither **Server B** or **Server C** have access to **Key A**. However, **Server B** and **Server C** share a private network with one another over **Network P**.

What I'd like to do is use the `ssh` or `scp` `ProxyCommand` option, if possible, to ssh into **Server B**  from **Server A** and `scp` files from **Server B** over to **Server C** but done *through the private network. Network P*.

Is chaining scp/ssh commands like this possible? If so, how do I do it?

Comment: This question was very difficult to follow (at least for me).  The relevance of A is unclear if B and C share a private network and you want to transfer files between them over that network - why can they not communicate directly?

Comment: Because they don't have the private key, Key A. So B can't log into C.

Comment: You cannot use the private network unless you have an access mechanism.  Either create another key or route traffic via A.

Comment: @tater I found a solution. Not sure if it's the idea one but it works. See answer below.

Comment: Actually, I have no idea if that is transferring files from Machine B to Machine A over the private network then down to my local machine over the pbulic netwrok, and back up to A over the public network or if it is just going from Machine B to A.

Answer (score 0):

I somehow managed to pull it off with this monstrosity:

```
scp -3 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i ~/.ssh/secret.pem -o \
ProxyCommand="ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no \
-i ~/.ssh/secret.pem -W %h:%p admin@205.85.32.42" \
admin@192.168.1.5:/home/admin/file.pdf admin@192.168.1.6:/home/admin
```